# How to implement Streaming Mode using Cloud Filter API (cfapi)?

Tags: filesystems, streaming, virtualfilesystem, virtual-drive

I am trying to implement streaming mode using Cloud Filter API. My aim is to create a drive with high security - the file content is available only when the drive is online and no data is stored on the client machine. If permissions are withdrawn, there will be no file content left on disk.

I set the [HydrationPolicyModifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootinfo.hydrationpolicymodifier?view=winrt-22000) to StreamingAllowed when registering the sync root:

```
StorageProviderSyncRootInfo.HydrationPolicyModifier = StorageProviderHydrationPolicyModifier.StreamingAllowed
```

According to the [StorageProviderHydrationPolicyModifier enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageproviderhydrationpolicymodifier?view=winrt-22000) docs, the StreamingAllowed value should prevent any data being stored on disk:

> This modifier does not allow the platform to store any data on disk
> returned by a sync provider.

However, when I unmount the sync root or if the app crushes, the hydrated files content remains in file system. It is not deleted even after machine reboot. I verified this using two different drive implementations, one of which is Cloud Mirror Microsoft sample.